# Query! how can i get total meals and cost from three tables for each user! This is my first question so sorry for the inconvenience

Tags: mysql, sql, database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rlndr.png)i have three tables users,meals,expense. I want to calculate users meal,expense between date display with a single query.
i have tried in many ways. Like

```
SELECT u.name as BorderName , SUM(e.expenseAmount) as expense  
FROM users u
INNER JOIN expenses  e on e.user_id=u.id 
WHERE e.expenseDate BETWEEN '2019.04-01' AND '2019.04.30' 
GROUP BY e.user_id
```

[image: my meal table]

[image: myexepnse table]

[image: My Expected Output is:]

Comment: Please describe your data in the question.  Text tables are preferable to images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do the aggregation inline views, with the inline view returning a single row per user_id, to avoid semi-Cartesian product (partial cross product)

Something like this:

```
SELECT u.name
     , IFNULL(t.tot_expenseamount,0)  AS tot_expense_amount
     , IFNULL(n.tot_noofmeal,0)       AS tot_no_of_meal
  FROM users u 
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT e.user_id 
              , SUM(e.expenseamount) AS tot_expenseamount
           FROM expense e
          WHERE e.expensedate >= '2019-04-01' + INTERVAL 0 MONTH
            AND e.expensedate  < '2019-04-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
          GROUP
             BY e.user_id
       ) t
    ON t.user_id = u.id
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT m.user_id
              , SUM(m.noofmeal) AS tot_noofmeal
           FROM meal m
          WHERE m.mealdate    >= '2019-04-01' + INTERVAL 0 MONTH
            AND m.mealdate     < '2019-04-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
          GROUP
             BY m.user_id
       ) n
    ON n.user_id = u.id
 ORDER
    BY u.name
```

Note that the inline view queries `n` and `t` return single row per user_id, with total expense amount or total number of meals.  For testing, each inline view query can be executed separately, to verify the results.

Comment: sir can you help me that how can i calculate total cost fo per suser in theis query !

totalcost= meal rate*total meal ;

(meal rate= sum expense/sum num of meal)

Comment: just add another expression to the SELECT list i.e. `, IFNULL(t.tot_expenseamount,0) / IFNULL(n.tot_noofmeal,0)       AS tot_expense_div_tot_no_of_meal`

Comment: it changes meal rate for every user !  but meal rate  will be same for all user ..